# MySQL update data from another database

Tags: mysql, database, append, prestashop

Once i made copy of databes of my internet shop (which runs on **prestashop**) to work on it. Now when I finished, the orginal database have some new products etc. And my point is to add these obcject to databse which I edited. Can you tell me, how to do it by MySQL?

I have access to phpMyAdmin, console MySQL and to files of databeses. 
Both of databeses (edited and orginal with new products) are on the same server.

- Orginal: maxihouse1
- Edited: maxihouse2.

*My theoretical solution is:* 
Add new records from **maxihouse2** to **maxihouse1**, but I have no idea how to jot down it in SQL language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CREATE TABLE AS .. SELECT` construct like below to get this done

```
use `maxihouse1`;

create table new_table(col1, col2, col3, .... , coln)
as
select col1, col2, col3, .... , coln 
from maxihouse2.dbo.old_table;
```

See more on [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

(OR)

If the `new_table` schema already exists in `maxihouse1` database then you can use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into `maxihouse1`.dbo.`new_table`(col1, col2, col3, .... , coln)
select col1, col2, col3, .... , coln from maxihouse2.dbo.old_table;
```

Comment: I mean to add records to existing tabels, but the problem is that the amount of these tabels is so high, that is too much work to specify each of them. So the question is: It is possible, to compare each table (of the same name in database1 and in database2), and if the tables are diffrent, add missing records?
<br/>
--example-------  
if( size(maxihouse1.ps_products_name) != size(maxihouse2.ps_product_name) ) 
add_missing_records_to_maxihouse2;

Comment: @Paweł, NO, I don't think so and even if it's; it would be very tedious/complex. just a note; consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.